# Python + Selenium: get span value from "ng-bind"

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I have Selenium code that goes to a page using chrome. Now at that page, there is this HTML;

```
<span ngbind="pageData.Message">Heloooo</span>
```

How can I get the value using python and Selenium? So only the `Heloooo`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS Selector for locating the element:

```
span[ngbind='pageData.Message']
```

Code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[ngbind='pageData.Message']")
print(element.text)  # Will print the "Heloooo" value.
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using XPath to get the text of the element:

```
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ngbind='pageData.Message']")
print(element1.text)
```

It's just another option.