# JavaScript get span value from “ng-bind”

Tags: javascript, ng-bind

There are many similar posts but I can't find my solution.

My code is:

```html
<span ng-bind="selected.S_date" class="ng-binding">Different value all the time here.</span>
```

I want to get the value `Different value all the time here` from the span.

I can do

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ng-binding')[55].textContent
```

Here the `55` is dynamic, value change.
Found [Python + Selenium: get span value from "ng-bind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693539/python-selenium-get-span-value-from-ng-bind) but I want to do with JavaScript.

Want to do similar is JavaScript?

Comment: You can use the same code, just instead of `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` use `document.querySelector`.

Comment: `ng-*` prefix indicates Angular/AngularJS framework, not vanilla js. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks Man. work perfectly. I was trying to find out for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution suggested by Heretic Monkey on the comment.

```
document.querySelector("span[ng-bind='selected.S_date']")
```